# Telerik RadWindow problem

Tags: c#, asp.net, telerik

I am kinda new to c# and I am kinda new to telerik. I have this problem:

I am opening a telerik window on the click of a button and then on the click of button placed in telerik window I want to update the grid (Telerik Grid) on parent window, I successfully update the telerik grid without doing a postback. But then when I click on the button in telerik window, it does its work and also updates the grid, but it again opens a new telrik  window.

I am not sure why this is happing. Below is a snippet of the code. Any suggestion would be greatly appreciated.

Java script functions on RejectLeaveRequest.aspx(telerik window):

```
function CloseAndRebind(args) {
    GetRadWindow().close();
    GetRadWindow().BrowserWindow.refreshGrid(args);
}

function GetRadWindow() {
    var oWindow = null;
    if (window.radWindow) {
        oWindow = window.radWindow; }
    else if (window.frameElement.radWindow) {
        oWindow = window.frameElement.radWindow;
    }
    return oWindow;
}
```

Code behind for RejectLeaveRequest.aspx.cs(telerik window):

```
protected void btnReject_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Code for delete records
    //
    ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Page.GetType(), "mykey", "CloseAndRebind(this);", true); // Call client method in radwindow page
}
```

Java script functions on Approval.aspx:

```
function refreshGrid() {
    $find("<%= RadAjaxManager1.ClientID %>").ajaxRequest("Rebind");
}

<telerik:RadAjaxManager ID="RadAjaxManager1" runat="server" OnAjaxRequest="RadAjaxManager1_AjaxRequest">
    <AjaxSettings>
        <telerik:AjaxSetting AjaxControlID="RadAjaxManager1">
            <UpdatedControls>
                <telerik:AjaxUpdatedControl ControlID="gvLeaveApproval" />
            </UpdatedControls>
        </telerik:AjaxSetting>
        <telerik:AjaxSetting AjaxControlID="gvLeaveApproval">
            <UpdatedControls>
                <telerik:AjaxUpdatedControl ControlID="gvLeaveApproval" />
            </UpdatedControls>
        </telerik:AjaxSetting>
    </AjaxSettings>
</telerik:RadAjaxManager>

<asp:UpdatePanel ID="updRadWindow" UpdateMode="Conditional" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <telerik:RadWindowManager ID="RadWindowManager1" runat="server" >
        </telerik:RadWindowManager>
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Code behind for Approval.aspx:

```
protected void RadAjaxManager1_AjaxRequest(object sender, AjaxRequestEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Argument == "Rebind")
    {
        SelectEmployeeLeaveRequested();
    }
}
```

Comment: You've posted a few questions... Surely you know how to format your code properly?

Comment: probably be a good idea to stick this on the telerik forums if you're having problems..! they are usually quite good!

Comment: Hi Bex, I posted the question on the telerik forum pages. I will add the reply from telerik here, if I get one...

Comment: how are you opening the radwindow? also why are you using a regular asp.net update panel to contain the radwindow manager?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this on the telerik demo site. It helped us with fixing the problem

http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/controls/examples/integration/gridandwindow/defaultcs.aspx?product=window